# Returns undefined when attempting to run JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getJSON('http://robloxplus.com:2052/inventory?username=itracking',   function(data){
 $.each(data, function(item){
 console.log(item['id'])
});
});`
```

returns undefined when attempting to run it on an external website. It is supposed to output each id of every item in that list (http://robloxplus.com:2052/inventory?username=itracking)

How do I fix this?

Edits>

I want to iterate over each individual id, each of these numbers "168167114": and "135470963": etc. etc. and fetch the data that follows that (i.e. the name:"", totalSerial:"")

Comment: If the website does not support [``CORS``](http://enable-cors.org/) then this cannot be fixed.

Comment: There's only one object returned, and it has a `id` property -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/L3z1t82v/, you shouldn't be iterating, or at least not iterating over that object, there are nested objects that also have an `id` property

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Has nothing to do with CORs in this case, bad use of each is the issue.

Comment: Please look at the docs for https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @epascarello: Re CORS - Could be a both/and. :-)

Comment: is the request being made on the same domains as `robloxplus.com` ?

Comment: The issue is the fact the data is not an array for data as OP acts like it is.

Comment: It might be that he's trying to iterate through ``(returned object).data.hat.data`` after tinkering around with the parsed object...

Comment: > I'm new to this.. I don't understand much about JavaScript and/or JQuery. @Pedro Lobito no, it's not.

Comment: Your use of each is wrong, and you are iterating over the wrong thing in the object that is being returned. What are you actually trying to loop over?

Comment: @epascarello I want to iterate over each individual id, each of these numbers "168167114": and "135470963": etc. etc. and fetch the data that follows that (i.e. the name:"", totalSerial:"")

Answer (score 0):

> is the request being made on the same domain as robloxplus.com ?
> I'm new to this.. I don't understand much about JavaScript and/or
> JQuery. @Pedro Lobito no, it's not. –

Explanation:

> HTTP requests from Javascript are traditionally bound by the Same
> Origin Policy, which means that your ajax requests must have the same
> domain and port. The common ways to get around this are JSON-P,
> Proxying and message passing via s. These all have their
> quirks, but the thing they generally have in common is legacy browser
> support.

---

## Solution

1 - If robloxplus.com is yours, you can [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

2 - If not, you can use [YQL (Yahoo! Query Language)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql) to bypass CORS

---

When one of the above options is fulfilled, you can make your json request, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://robloxplus.com:2052/inventory?username=itracking',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {  
     $.each(data.id, function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Which solution did you choose? CORS or YQL ?